# Копирование изображения из директории в директорию, масштабирование

Tags: php

Есть рабочий код, однако работает он только для jpeg. Png сохраняются, но не открываются.

```
$images_list = scandir('data/images/products');
//var_dump($images_list);
$images_list_new = array();
$test = "thu";
$test_2 = "png";
$count = 0;
for ($i=0;$i<count($images_list);$i++){

   if (strcasecmp(substr($images_list[$i], 0 ,3), $test) == 0) {}
   else {$images_list_new[$count] = $images_list[$i]; $count++;}
}


$width = 200;
$height = 200;
for ($i=3;$i<count($images_list_new);$i++) {
   $width = 200;
   $height = 200;
   list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize('data/images/products/'.$images_list_new[$i]);

    $ratio_orig = $width_orig / $height_orig;
    echo $width_orig . " " . $height_orig . '<br>';
    if ($width / $height > $ratio_orig) {
        $width = $height * $ratio_orig;
    } else {
        $height = $width / $ratio_orig;
    }


    $file = "data/images/new_".$images_list_new[$i];
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
//$image =     imagecreatefromjpeg('data/images/products/'.$images_list_new[$i]);
    $image = imageCreateFromAny('data/images/products/'.$images_list_new[$i]);

    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
    if (strcasecmp(substr($images_list[$i], 0 ,3), $test) == 0) {imagepng($image_p, $file);}
    else {
    imagejpeg($image_p, $file);
}
}
```

Comment: Вызывает сомнение последние условие, которое проверяет `strcasecmp(substr($images_list[$i], 0 ,3), $test) == 0` - это условие точно выполняется? Попробуйте отладить эту часть кода, не совсем ясна логика, что на что там проверяется.

Comment: это проверка на начало файла.
отсеивание картинок идет. оно выполняется. получается массив из имен картинок.

Comment: в конце есть похожее условие, здесь я проверяю если конец файла png

Answer (score 0):

Разве есть встроенная функция imageCreateFromAny? Если требуется открывать только jpeg или png и можно доверять расширению файла, лучше написать свою функцию:

```
function imageCreateFromAny( $filename)
{
    if (!file_exists($filename)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('File "'.$filename.'" not found.');
    }
    switch ( strtolower( pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ))) {
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg':
            return imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        break;

        case 'png':
            return imagecreatefrompng($filename);
        break;

        default:
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('File "'.$filename.'" is not valid jpg or png image.');
        break;
    }
}
```

Кстати, для более сложных манипуляций с картинками советую использовать [IMagick](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php) (PHP-расширение, работающее с API ImageMagick)

Comment: imagecreatefromAny - самописная функция, примерно как у вас. imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig); на вот этой стадии косяк, походу для пнг какие то приготовления нужны.